# keep zoom while user interaction matlab

Tags: matlab, zooming, axes

Here's my problem: I have an axes object in a figure. 
The user can draw a bunch of points on the image. 
Up to this point, everything is working as it should.

Now the user shall be able to zoom, draw some points on the zoomed image, and revert back to the original image once he/she has done.

I have a function updateVisualization that is called every time there is a change on the axes made by the user.

In this function, I tried to use

```
zoom(h, 'reset');
imagesc(updated_img);
zoom(h, 'out');
```

This solution keeps the zoom every the user does a modification :-) however, once the user is done, he/she cannot go back to the original zoom level.

What should I do?

Comment: How about setting `xlim` and `ylim` instead of using zoom?

Comment: I just did it! Put it as an answer, I'll upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% Saving zoom level

xlim = get(handles.axes, 'XLim');
ylim = get(handles.axes, 'YLim');

% Displaying image

imagesc(im, 'Parent', handles.axes, 'ButtonDownFcn', @axes_ButtonDownFcn);

% Setting saved zoom level. 

set(handles.axes, 'XLim', xlim);
set(handles.axes, 'YLim', ylim);
```